# Make .NET WebApi service deserialize recieved JSON as child object

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, serialization

The system i am developing is using DataContractJsonSerializer.
The service looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("RunQuery")]
public List<BIResultRecord> RunQuery(BIQuery query) {
    // Logic
}
```

The BIQuery class hierarchy is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(BIQuery1))]
public class BIQuery
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Member { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public QueryTypeEnum QueryType { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class BIQuery1 : BIQuery
{
    public BIQuery1()
    {
        QueryType = QueryTypeEnum.Type1;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public ClassSpecificObject Object { get; set; }       
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**:

Although i am sending BIQuery1 as a json object it is always deserialized (in my RunQuery method) as the parent object (BIQuery).

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**:

I've removed the default formatter and added a new one:

```
public class DataContractJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override DataContractJsonSerializer CreateDataContractSerializer(Type type)
    {
        return new DataContractJsonSerializer(type, new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings() { EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.AsNeeded });
    }

}
```

I serialized the object in .NET to see the JSON structure and 
cloning it to the request. I saw that it adds

```
"__type" : "BIQuery1"
```

to the JSON, which i'm using as well and it changed nothing.

Please help!

**MORE DETAILS**

The .NET system (client and server) runs in production as is, so only minor changes currently allowed. I'm making also a web client that would work with the existing services over REST.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost, Route("RunQuery")]
public List<BIResultRecord> RunQuery(BIQuery query) {
// Logic
}
```

Your argument in the RunQuery method is the of type BIQuery object. It is deserializing as a BIQuery object because that is the type you are telling the method it will be passed. If you are passing an object of the type BIQuery1 to the method, do this instead:

```
[HttpPost, Route("RunQuery")]
public List<BIResultRecord> RunQuery(BIQuery1 query) {
// Logic
}
```

Comment: This is intentional. This service already works with a .NET production client as is. In addition, the logic inside RunQuery is generic so i wouldn't want to copy it for each child.